# how to install python module via terminal?

Tags: python, pycharm

Recently while doing a webcrawler project in python, I was using PyCharm and had to download and install an external module.

[Installing on PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl6He.png)

Does anyone knows how to install those modules using unix terminal?

Comment: [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) perhaps?

Comment: it works.. just needed to know how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm uses pip underneath. If you have pip installed you just type on the terminal:

```
pip install "module name"
```